# Show/Hide of a div doesn't work sometimes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, class, helper, division

I have an `aura:component` which have two `divs` inside it. I run a query on my controller apex class and based on the returned value from the query, i want to hide or show any one of the div. Based on [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005n0BQAQ) answer, i wrote the code like this:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global"
            controller="ControllerClass">

     <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getType}" />

     <div class="buyer">
           <!--rest of the code-->
     </div>

     <div class="seller">
           <!--rest of the code-->
     </div>

</aura:component>
```

helper.js:

```
    getType: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getUserType");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
             var type = response.getReturnValue();
             if (type === 'buyer') {
                  var elements1 = document.getElementsByClassName("buyer");
                  elements1[0].style.display = 'block';
                  var elements2 = document.getElementsByClassName("seller");
                  elements2[0].style.display = 'none';
             }
             if (type === 'seller') {
                  var elements1 = document.getElementsByClassName("buyer");
                  elements1[0].style.display = 'none';
                  var elements2 = document.getElementsByClassName("seller");
                  elements2[0].style.display = 'block';
             }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

This code works fine most of the time. **But, sometimes even if I get the response value correct, both divs will be visible**. I happens very rarely. I will have reload the page again to solve it. I couldn't find the reason why. So, what could be the problem? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you implemented is fine. I assume it could be because of cache issue. However, the way you implemented is not the best practice per-se. You should be using [aura:if](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation).

Below is how it would look like:

COMPONENT:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global"
                controller="ControllerClass">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getType}" />
    <aura:attribute name="showBuyer" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="showSeller" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showBuyer}">
        <div class="buyer">
            <!--rest of the code-->
        </div>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSeller}">
        <div class="seller">
            <!--rest of the code-->
        </div>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
getType: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get('c.getUserType');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var type = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set('v.showBuyer', type === 'buyer');
        component.set('v.showSeller', type === 'seller');
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the asnwer. so whats the differece between `<aura:if>` and `<aura:renderIf>`

Comment: [renderIf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:renderIf/documentation) is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try these options:

```
1. Use elements1[0].style="display:none"; //instead of .style.display
```

OR 
Define an aura attribute and use aura:renderIf
 2.

```
     <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.truthy}">
        True
        <aura:set attribute="else">
          False
        </aura:set>
      </aura:renderIf>
```